# How much do you have to play to make up the difference in the pay VS free editions of Lord of the Rings Online?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I'm intrigued by LOTRO now being free.  I only play MMOs casually anyway, so I'm already behind the times.  How much longer/what extra work is involved to catch up to someone who has a pay account?  Assuming we start at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure we can really answer this question, as it seems very subjective. "Catch up" in what regard? It depends on how much time and money you're willing to put in, whether you plan on buying Turbine Points or not, etc. The level cap is 50 for F2P and 65 for someone with both expansions, so theoretically, you could never "catch up" in that sense.

Comment: It's definitely possible to catch up, it just takes a lot longer.

Comment: No, you can level to 75 regardless of account, you'll just be "grinding" a bit more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 different levels of player: people who have an current, active account are **VIP**'s, people who have paid for a subscription or expansion at some point in the past are **Premiums**, and everyone else is **F2P**.

You will have to focus on earning Turbine Points by grinding out achievements/deeds to unlock content past the first 3 'free' zones. I believe it is possible to unlock all zones by grinding deeds/TP's; I haven't done the math, but [some sites](http://forums.lotro.com/showthread.php?356764-TP-Flow-Earn-all-the-content-by-playing) [have](http://lotro.mmorsel.com/p/tpfinder.html).